# Comment out and uncomment cron job containing a certain word

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cron

I have some script running with cron and I need to stop them, so I want to build a shell script that comments out cron jobs containing a certain word.

How can I comment out and uncomment the cron job containing "start_bots" through shell script? I saw some solutions using "sed", but I'm not familiar with it.

```
*/3 * * * * /home/pi/Development/instabot.py/start_bots.sh
0 */3 * * * /home/pi/Development/instabot.py/stop_bots.sh
0 0 */3 * * /home/pi/Development/instabot.py/remove_logs.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i /start_bots/s/^/#/ cronfile
```

- The -i option streams the edited content into a new file and then renames it behind the scenes.
- `/start_bots/` matches a line with `start_bots`
- `s` do the substitution on the lines matched above
- Substitution will insert a comment character `#` at the beginning of the line `^`(`^` represent the beginning of the line).

Comment: I get this message "sed: 1: "cronfile": command c expects \ followed by text" running "sed -i /start_bots/s/^/#/ cronfile" on terminal.

Comment: what is the question? you are getting error? did you replace `cronfile` with the name of you file.

Comment: I made it with `crontab -l | sed '/restart_bots/s/^/#/' | crontab -`!

Comment: what is the last part of the command `crontab -` ?